# How can I get a Dialog style activity window to fill the screen?

Tags: android, user-interface, dialog

I am using an activity with the dialog theme set, and I want it to be full screen. I tried all sorts of things, even going through the WindowManager to expand the window to full width and height manually, but nothing works.

Apparently, a dialog window (or an activity with the dialog theme) will only expand according to its contents, but even that doesn't always work. For instance, I show a progress bar circle which has width and height set to FILL_PARENT (so does its layout container), but still, the dialog wraps around the much smaller progress bar instead of filling the screen.

There must be a way of displaying something small inside a dialog window but have it expand to full screen size without its content resizing as well?

Comment: Interesting note:
When setting the layout container's width and height to an actual value in pixels, then the dialog resizes accordingly. But when setting it to FILL_PARENT, then it doesn't...

Comment: Really? The layout the activity is instantiating, does it have a parent Relative or LinearLayout tag that is set to height and width of fill_parent? I've implemented a few activities with a dialog theme and never had a problem with it taking up the entire screen.

Comment: Yes, the activity has a LinearLayout set to FILL_PARENT for both width and height.

Comment: I sort of solved the problem by using a workaround, but since this is not a good solution, I'll leave the question open.

What I did was to subclass LinearLayout and override its onMeasure() method, which is responsible for determining the size of the view during a layouting cycle, and fix it to the screen width and height. This is not correct though, since this does not take into account the space occupied by the menu bars, so the container will actually be taller than it looks like on the screen (with all the weird side effects like children disappearing in non visible areas of the screen).

Comment: I found the correct solution, see my answer below.

Comment: see this answer in other thread, maybe it could help

http://stackoverflow.com/a/7655350/3214497

Answer (score 327, accepted):

I found the solution:

In your activity which has the `Theme.Dialog` style set, do this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
}
```

It's important that you call `Window.setLayout()` *after* you call `setContentView()`, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Thanks, saved my time , nowhere I would have figured this out ! but any idea why we have to explicitly specify in code , why fill_parent does not work through xml for activities with theme dialog ?

Comment: My dialog won't fill width, not by XML, and not by this method.
I'm eating my nails.

Comment: And it is: `import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;`

Comment: Cool its really work. But not getting why we need to define explicitly. As i have already define fill_parent in xml.

Comment: Works great, But you may prefer to use LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT especially for the height (2nd parameter).

Comment: FILL_PARENT is deprecated now, use MATCH_PARENT instead

Comment: Not all right!                         dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

Comment: It's not filling the entire screen, it's like it has a small padding on each side.

Comment: i want a full screen width dialog, i used **dialog.getWindow()** and also **getWindow()**, but my dialog still not taking full width of screen, still behind screen is showing from both sides(left & right). any solution for dialog ?

Comment: I don't know if it's work for default dialog style, but i am using Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog and it give padding to each sides(top, right, bottom and left). I need to use Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog, because i use AppCompatActivity to support lower android versions.

Comment: If you guys still struggle with padding on the dialog itself, you can see my answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/39590004/3940133

Comment: Can i customize the size for it?

Answer (score 73):

You may add this values to your style android:windowMinWidthMajor and android:windowMinWidthMinor

```
<style name="Theme_Dialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    ...
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">97%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">97%</item>
</style>
```

Comment: most easiest solution. It is also working with appcompat support library. Thanks.

Comment: This should be accepted answer. The most proper and clean way to do it. Consider using parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog"

Comment: This seems like it should work, but it doesn't for me.  Hmm, I wonder why.  Perhaps things have changed since 2014.

Answer (score 54):

I just want to fill only 80% of the screen for that I did like this below

```
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int screenWidth = (int) (metrics.widthPixels * 0.80);

        setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);

        getWindow().setLayout(screenWidth, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); //set below the setContentview
```

it works only when I put the getwindow().setLayout... line below the setContentView(..)

thanks @Matthias

Answer (score 13):

Wrap your **dialog_custom_layout.xml** into **RelativeLayout** instead of any other layout.That worked for me.

Comment: Same here, Width and Height were completely wrong and couldn't figure out how to fix.  Converting the root layout to a RelativeLayout fixed my issues as well!

Answer (score 9):

**For Dialog**
This may helpful for someone.
I want a dialog to take full width of screen. searched a lot but nothing found useful. Finally this worked for me:

```
mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_custom_dialog);
mDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

after adding this, my dialog appears in full width of screen.

Answer (score 7):

This answer is a workaround **for those who use "Theme.AppCompat.Dialog" or any other "Theme.AppCompat.Dialog" descendants** like "Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog", "Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog", etc.
I myself has to use AppCompat dialog because i use AppCompatActivity as extends for all my activities. There will be a problem that make the dialog has padding on every sides(top, right, bottom and left) if we use the accepted answer.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
}
```

On your Activity's style, add these code

```
<style name="DialogActivityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
</style>
```

As you may notice, the problem that generate padding to our dialog is "android:windowBackground", so here i make the window background to null.

Answer (score 2):

Set a minimum width at the top most layout.

```
android:minWidth="300dp"
```

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:minWidth="300dp">

<!-- Put remaining contents here -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Matthias' answer is mostly right but it's still not filling the entire screen as it has a small padding on each side (pointed out by @Holmes). In addition to his code, we could fix this by extending Theme.Dialog style and add some attributes like this.

```
<style name="MyDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Then we simply declare Activity with theme set to `MyDialog`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".FooActivity"
    android:theme="@style/MyDialog" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be helpful for someone like me. Create custom dialog style:

```
<style name="MyDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml` file set theme for wanted activity:

```
<activity
        android:name=".CustomDialog"
        ...
        android:theme="@style/MyDialog"/>
```

That is all, no need to call methods programaticaly.

Comment: still show padding on each sides(top, right, bottom and left) and if we need to show status bar too, this solution will fail

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/39590004/3940133 if you have padding on each sides

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file where our activity is defined

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourPopUpActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" >
    </activity>
```

without action bar

```
<activity android:name=".YourPopUpActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar"/>
```