# Android dialog width

Tags: android, dialog, width

I can't seem to control the dialog width.  I have a simple layout like so`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"> 

    <ScrollView 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout     android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/name_prompt_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/name_prompt"
            android:padding="10dip"/>

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/name_inp" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxLength="48"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/t1_prompt_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/t1_prompt"
            android:padding="10dip"/>

        <Spinner 
            android:id="@+id/t1_inp" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxLength="48"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:entries= "@array/t1_allowed_values" />

         </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

for some reason the dialog is only wide enough for  the text input field about 11 chars wide.  How do I make the dialog width fill the screen?

Comment: The only solution that worked for me was this one :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306503/how-to-make-an-alert-dialog-fill-90-of-srceen-size/6631310#6631310

Answer (score 86):

I had the same problem.

I used following code to make dialog fill_parent and it worked fine.

```
public class SharePost extends Dialog
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.adaptor_contentsharepost);

        LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.height = LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
        getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params);
    }
}
```

layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/dialogWidth"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    contents here

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: for some reason the xml layout parameters I set for width/height were not working on my dialog but this worked great! +1

Comment: This worked for me but only if I reset the params *after* calling `show()`.

Comment: `fill_parent` is now deprecated in favor of `match_parent`.

Answer (score 58):

I'm using:

```
getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: FILL_PARENT is now deprecated.

Comment: Should use MATCH_PARENT instead

Comment: So it will be like: **dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);**

Answer (score 16):

Set a minimum width at the top most layout.

```
android:minWidth="300dp"
```

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:minWidth="300dp">

<!-- Put remaining contents here -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If it doesn't work in the outermost layout, as it didn't for me, it works by setting it in one of the layout elements, like a title bar.

Comment: Better solution for me as I wanted to keep the definition entirely in XML and not have to fix it up in the code. Thanks for pointing this attribute out!

Comment: This worked for me with Kotlin and ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 13):

As Matthias points at out [How can I get a Dialog style activity window to fill the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362723/how-can-i-get-a-dialog-style-activity-window-to-fill-the-screen/1693716#1693716) UMAR's solution works, but only if the window attributes are set AFTER setContentView() is called.

Comment: Actually, as it is stated here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406804/how-to-control-the-width-and-height-of-default-alert-dialog-in-android], it works only after .show() (at least for me).

Answer (score 8):

Try this. It works for me.

```
    dialog = new Dialog(Activity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.feedback_popup);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Comment: If you do this in onActivityCreated if you are using DialogFragment will work.<br>        getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes().width = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.uid_alert_dialog_width); should also work

Answer (score 0):

Since API 8 FILL_PARENT is deprecated. Use MATCH_PARENT instead.

```
params.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
```

Comment: this is the answer to another question... deprecated doesn't mean disabled (yet)

Comment: I agree, deprecated doesn't mean disabled, but it means that even if you can keep using it you might not do it, as is likely to be removed in a next version.

Comment: still not the answer to this question in particular. Since FILL_PARENT still works, you can't expect to solve this question by replacing by a preferred synonym.