# AlertDialog with too large text and width

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am using Android 2.3

I have an alertdialog in my app. Here the code:

```
final CharSequence[] items = { "Entfernen", "Auswählen",
                    "Editieren", "Zurücksetzen", "Abbrechen" };

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle(productName);
            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {...}
```

I have a strange problem: The Dialog always fills the whole width of my display. And therefore the text of the selectors is very large. 
How can I limit this? Either textsize or width of this dialog...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406804/how-to-control-the-width-and-height-of-default-alert-dialog-in-android

the third answer is what you are looking for, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the following method of your alert dialog to inflate a custom xml into your alert dialog.

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_dialog);
```

After calling this, you would need to set TextView/ImageView variables, just like how you would with activities.

For a better example, check out Android API Docs.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Comment: I know how to create custom dialogs. But it seems strange for me, that the default alertdialog is streched to whole width of screen.

Comment: It'd be great if you could show me some screenshots and code snippets of what you are doing.

Comment: The code you can see in my post. I simply show the dialog. But the entries textsize is strangly very large