# DialogFragment.getDialog returns null

Tags: android

I am trying to get the `Dialog` I have created with an extended `DialogFragment` using `DialogFragment.getDialog()` but it returns null.

Basically I want to alter the text in the layout from the `FragmentActivity` which creates and shows the `DialogFragment`.

Comment: have you solved it? I'm running into the same question

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You're calling `getDialog()` too early in the `DialogFragment`'s life cycle.

`getDialog()` simply returns the private variable `mDialog` from the `DialogFragment`.

When a `DialogFragment` is instantiated `mDialog` is null, and then it gets set when `onCreateDialog` is fired inside `getLayoutInflater(Bundle savedInstanceState)`, so you have to call `getDialog` after `onCreateDialog`.

For example, the order of some common methods called is `onCreate`, `onCreateDialog`, and `onCreateView`, `onStart`. So, you can call `getDialog` and have it return something in `onCreateView` or `onStart`, but not in `onCreate` or `onCreateDialog`.

Even though `onStart` is called [`called when the Fragment is visible to the user`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#onStart%28%29), adjusting the layout of the fragment at that point looks fine.... for example setting the width and height using `getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(..., ...);` doesn't make the fragment appear to change size, but just appears to have the newly set size.

Comment: Even in the onCreateView,onStart and onResume the getDialog() returns null for me ...any advices?

Comment: I can't seem to figure it out still. I am coming from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907104/alertdialog-with-custom-view-resize-to-wrap-the-views-content

My dialog expands the entire width of the phone which it shouldn't be. It doesn't have content to expand that entire length. This is so annoying since according to that answer I must call setLayoutParams after show which apparently I cannot do if I inherited DialogFragment :/

Answer (score 64):

Try calling executePendingTransactions() from the available FragmentManager.

```
    dialogFragment = new DialogFragment();
        ...
    dialogFragment.show(mFragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "Dialog");
    mFragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

    Dialog d = dialogFragment.getDialog()
        ...
```

Comment: This is due to the deferred execution of transaction changes. We can force the FragmentTransaction instance's work to be executed immediately by calling the FragmentManager class' executePendingTransactions() method. When a call to the executePendingExecutions() method returns, we know that all the committed FragmentTransaction work has been performed.

Comment: It works! But what an obscure call - I would have thought that .show would trigger all the pending fragments

Answer (score 7):

There is 2 way to show DialogFragment:

```
  void showDialog() { 
    // Create the fragment and show it as a dialog. 
    DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(); 
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}
```

And

```
 FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(); 
ft.add(R.id.embedded, newFragment);
ft.commit();
```

You can only get a nonNull dialog when using the first way.

Comment: is there a way to set dialog location using the second method ?

Comment: Using the first case I still had the `getDialog() = null` on some devices (or under some, yet unknown to me, circumstances - that is, I see a small amount of crashes in production, but not when I'm testing it)

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Dialog extends DialogFragment {

private DialogListener dialogListener;


public void setDialogListener(DialogListener dialogListener) {
    this.dialogListener = dialogListener;
}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    if (null != dialogListener) {
        dialogListener.onDismiss();
    }
}

public interface DialogListener {
    void onDismiss();
}
```

}

in Activity
...

```
  Dialog  dialog= new Dialog();
        dialog.setDialogListener(new Dialog.DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss() {
                Foo()..
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason for why `getDialog()` might return `null` after the dialog has been constructed and properly stored in `mDialog` is an accidental invocation of `dismiss()` on the `DialogFragment`.

When `dismiss()` is called, it will reset the `mDialog` field to `null` so that subsequent invocations of `getDialog()` will return `null` instead of the previously constructed dialog.

In my case, `dismiss()` was called to handle an error situation / side-case in the `DialogFragment`'s `onActivityCreated()` method. Subsequently trying to use `getDialog()` from the `onResume()` method returned `null`.

Also refer to the source code of the `DialogFragment` class, specifically its `dismissInternal(boolean allowStateLoss)` method:

https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/pie-platform-release/core/java/android/app/DialogFragment.java