# How to set the height and width of the Default Alert Dialog

Tags: android

I have a problem in setting the height and width of an Alert Dialog, below is my Code that i have written in OnCreateDialog() method:

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context ,AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT)
    .setTitle("Title")        
    .setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            switch(which){

            case 0:
                //some Code
            break;
            case 1:                 
                //some Code
            break;
            }

        }
    })
    .create();


WindowManager.LayoutParams WMLP = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();


WMLP.x = 80;   //x position
WMLP.y = -100;   //y position
WMLP.height = 100;
WMLP.width = 100;

dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(WMLP);
     //OR
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(100, 100);
```

Kindly tell me what is the problem here in the Code. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406804/how-to-control-the-width-and-height-of-default-alert-dialog-in-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406804/how-to-control-the-width-and-height-of-default-alert-dialog-in-android

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the parameters for `Height` & `Width` after `alertDialog.show();`

So you need to call,

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(100, 100);
```

After calling

```
alertDialog.show();
```

For more check [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6922903/726863) answer.

Comment: Thanks , saved my time

Comment: Kind of makes sense, but somehow also doesn't. Anyway, I wished I read this answer 2 hours ago! Thanks.