# Custom AlertDialog with RecyclerView - list is always empty

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog

First, I created activity with RecyclerView, it works fine. My original code:

activity_agreements.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:inputType="none|text|textPersonName"
        android:text="* required fields"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnGetSelected"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGetSelected"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:text="I agree"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Agreements list passed to ActivityAgreements and adapter setup:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_agreements);

        btnGetSelected = findViewById(R.id.btnGetSelected);
        list = findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        list.setHasFixedSize(true);


        agreements = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("agreements");



        AgreementsAdapter adapter = new AgreementsAdapter(this.agreements);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My adapter code:

```
public class AgreementsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AgreementsAdapter.ViewHolder>
{

    ArrayList<Agreement> agreements;

    public AgreementsAdapter(List<Agreement> agreements)
    {
        this.agreements = new ArrayList<>(agreements);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.agreement_list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        holder.bindData(agreements.get(position));
        holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(agreements.get(position).getAccepted());
        //holder.checkbox.setFloorUnCheckedColor(agreements.get(position).getRequired()? Color.rgb(255,0,0):Color.rgb(0,255,0) );
        holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> agreements.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setAccepted(isChecked));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return agreements.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        private TextView textAgreementName;
        private AppCompatCheckBox checkbox;

        public ViewHolder(View v)
        {
            super(v);
            //textAgreementName = v.findViewById(R.id.text_agreement_name);
            checkbox = v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_agreement_accepted);
        }

        public void bindData(Agreement agreement)
        {
            //checkbox.setFloorUnCheckedColor(agreement.getRequired()? Color.rgb(255,0,0):Color.rgb(0,0,255) );
            /*if(agreement.getRequired())
            {
                textAgreementName.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                textAgreementName.setText(agreement.getName() + " *");
            }
            else
                textAgreementName.setText(agreement.getName());*/


            if(agreement.getRequired())
            {
                checkbox.setText(agreement.getName() + " *");
                checkbox.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            }
            else
            {
                checkbox.setText(agreement.getName());
            }




        }
    }
}
```

All is fine, activity with list shows itself without any problems. Now, I want to use AlertDialog, not activity to display agreements list. I'm trying to create AlertDialog this way (in main activity):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_agreements, null);
            alertDialog.setView(convertView);


            RecyclerView list = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list);
            list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            list.setHasFixedSize(true);

            AgreementsAdapter adapter = new AgreementsAdapter(agreements);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);



           alertDialog.show();
```

`agreements` variable contains agreements list (the same as previously passed to AgrrementsActivity). But it does not work - dialog is shown with custom layout, but list is always empty.

Can anybody point me what am I missing?

New code with fixed size and other suggestions:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_agreements, null);



            RecyclerView list = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list);
            list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            list.setHasFixedSize(true);

            AgreementsAdapter adapter = new AgreementsAdapter(agreements);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            alertDialog.setView(convertView);

            AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400);



           dialog.show();
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Do you want to show recyclerview inside Dialog ?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. Custom layout as shown above, moved from activity to dialog

Comment: Try alertDialog.setView(convertView); below list.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Still list is empty

Comment: Can you please check android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" of recycler view

Comment: Try: RecyclerView list = alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.list);

Comment: `android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="0dp" ` is already there. There is no `findViewById` method available in alert dialog.

Comment: try `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your `AgreementsAdapter` after `alertDialog.show()` call

Comment: Still the same...

Comment: First remove 0dp from height and width both and give some hardcoded value (ONLY to check if this is being rendered). Second, findview and setup related things you should do after calling dialog.show();

Comment: Well, indeed it's being rendered and it has content. List is visible if hardcoded values used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your RecyclerView is probably showing the list, but it has a height of 0 so it looks empty.

Dialog size is kind of tricky, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406804/how-to-control-the-width-and-height-of-the-default-alert-dialog-in-android) and try to give it a fixed height (maybe a percent of your screen height).

Comment: AlertDialog has no method `getWindow`

Comment: You should use the compat library (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AlertDialog), which has the getWindow method.

Comment: Well, ok I managed to set size but it has no effect, size is the same and still no list shown - question updated

Comment: You ansewer is right. List is there, but unlike inside Activity, now it has 0 size. Do you have any idea how co correclty render it? You above solution (set dialog size) has no effect

Comment: Ok, so it finally works. I set `android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and it seems to be fine now

Answer (score 3):

I know it is very late to answer this question but I have also faced the same issue. So for the people who is still facing this issue can use below technique.

If you are using **Recycler View with constraint layout** and have set the `layout_height="0"` in alert dialog then u will not be able to see the recycler View list. to resolve this issue set this

```
app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
```

in **recyclerview**

Answer (score 0):

after hours looking for the best way to use RecyclerView and AlertDialog and ConstraintLayout, solution:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/abc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/abc" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBarFavorito"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/abc" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Answer (score 0):

for Using recyclerview in alertdialogue,u should be a bit tricky.As u use match parent,so width of recyclerview is 0 because recyclerviews dimension is set before alertdialogue is created.So you do such:

1)use runnable and set your adapter (or other activities we do with recyclerview) 1 sec delaying

or,
2)when you initialize recyclerview,then just set it's layoutparams programmactically. This solved my issue.(don't use this code blindly,i just copied it from my codes,and it may not be suitable for your one.rather just get idea about the issue.)

```
member_list.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```