# Setting width and height to AlertDialog with custom layout doesn't apply correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

The text in my dialog is too long, and it mixes with buttons. So I figured out I should change the size of the dialog.

**upd.:** To make it clear, the question is if it's possible to change the size of the alert dialog in such way so that these changes apply to a layout, and how? If it is really impossible, why and what are the alternatives.

Here is how I am trying to do it in my code, according to answers [in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406804/how-to-control-the-width-and-height-of-the-default-alert-dialog-in-android):

```
    int matchParent = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    rulesDialog.show();
    rulesDialog.getWindow().setLayout(matchParent, matchParent);
```

And I got this, it just adds the white gap:

[image]

Also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406804/how-to-control-the-width-and-height-of-the-default-alert-dialog-in-android#answer-55502314). That didn't work at all.
I also tried to add this line with the same approach, did nothing:

```
<item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
```

Here is xml code of a layout passed to the `AlertDialog.Builder`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/beige">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:textColor="@color/brown"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="@string/info_text"
        android:id="@+id/info_text"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/info_text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/ok"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@color/orange"
        android:background="@color/blank"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/ok"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/info_text"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ok"
        android:text="@string/renew_record"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@color/orange"
        android:background="@color/blank"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/renew_record"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**upd.:** I've found that this code works:

```
rulesDialog.show();
int matchParent = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
rulesDialog.getWindow().setLayout(matchParent, matchParent);
rulesDialog.setContentView(R.layout.info);
```

Solves the white gap problem totally.
For some case, the problem with overlapping still exists. As far as I understand, that's a common problem for `RelativeLayout`, now I am investigating it.

**upd.:** Yes, I should've deleted `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` line from the `TextView`. Now all works fine with two latter fixes, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use scroll view in your .xml or enable scrolling in textview itself. I think the later is more simple and as follows.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ....  
        android:maxLines="7"   <-- play with this number to best suit your expectations-->
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        />
```

Finally in your .java/.kt file.

```
textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: That may be a solution. However, I'd like to know if it's possible to change the size of the AlertDialog properly for the future use.

Comment: Hm, strange, I've tried this, and the buttons somehow still overlap the text, even though the size of the dialog became smaller.

Comment: Did you tired setting height = wrap_content for the root element (Relative layout) to resize your dialog box based on you size of text.

Comment: Change relative to constraint layout / linear layout , it might help with overlapping issue.

Comment: setting height = wrap_content wouldn't work because AlertDialog dumps the layout parameters of the layout root, that's why we usually pass null as a parent when inflating the layout.