# How do I display a full-width DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to create a custom `DialogFragment`, that extends over the whole width of my screen (or rather, parent fragment). Although I can make the borders of the `DialogFragment` transparent, there still is a padding on the right and left that I cannot get rid of.

This is my Fragment:

```
public static class LoaderDialog extends DialogFragment {

    static LoaderDialog newInstance() {
        LoaderDialog f = new LoaderDialog();

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loader_f, container, false);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams p = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
        p.y = getSupportActionBar().getHeight();

        getDialog().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        getDialog().getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
        getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(p);

        return view;
    }
}
```

This is a picture, how it looks like: 
[image: screenshot]

As you can see, the DialogFragment (the red thing) has some margins on the side. I want those to be gone. Any idea how to do this (in java, if possible)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android dialog width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634850/android-dialog-width)

Comment: Thank you for the link. However, I tried `p.width = LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;` before without success. So the answer of UMAR seems not to help me.

Answer (score 14):

You can use:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
wmlp.gravity = Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL;
```

Full example:

```
public class TextEditor extends DialogFragment {

    public TextEditor () {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_text_editor, container);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
        wmlp.gravity = Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL;

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: This Solution Worked , but root layout should not be Coordinator Layout

Comment: Thanks a lot. Work like gem.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
p.horizontalMargin = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this style for DialogFragment

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
```

or use this code in onCreateView method of DialogFragment

```
    Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth();
    int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, **220**, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(width,px);
```

ps. **220** is DialogFragment height, change it as u wish

Answer (score 0):

Create a style element in your style.xml file. Copy the code below to your style.xml file

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
```

Then in the createDialog method of your DialogFragment class,

```
dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.CustomDialog);
```

This is working for me and hope this will help you too

Answer (score -1):

Try to use LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT instead. Fill_parent is drepecated. Moreover if you have set a padding for your view that is normal that is not fill its parent's view.

Comment: MATCH_PARENT produces the same result

Comment: Yes but if you do applications for Android 2.2+ you should go for MATCH_PARENT instead of FILL_PARENT. The renaming happend in api level 8.

Comment: This doesn't matter at all, because both of them represent the same value in code (-1 to be exact)