# Inflating a View inside one of two Fragments

Tags: android, view, popup, fragment, android-inflate

in my Android application (for tablets), I have a two pane layout. On the left is a fragment containing a navigation menu of sorts, and on the right is a fragment loaded with buttons.

Pressing one of these buttons should result in a AlertDialog popping up. It does, however it pops up over the entire application, instead of just that one fragment. Everything else works perfectly.

I'd be eternally grateful if we could find a solution for this particular issue :)

Thank you!

Comment: One little update: it occured to me that I could transfer each and every one of my alertdialog xmls inside my fragment, but I'd like to see a solution done programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9467026/4428462) should be what you need. To change the size of your dialog, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2634850/4428462).

Alternatively, you could change the layout of your fragment when the button is clicked, which might be better or look nicer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can override a dialog to solute this problem