# remove extra real-estate from top of custom dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-relativelayout

I created a custom dialog that I'm dynamically putting views into via a RelativeLayout.  Every time the dialog is displayed, it shows all my child views just great, but it has some space at the top that I can not account for.  I'm assuming this is reserved for a "title" of the dialog (which I won't have).  Is there a way to remove that space and have my custom dialog just wrap the contents that I'm putting in?

here is the xml for the layout:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/handlay"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />  
</LinearLayout>
```

incidentally, I've tried just having the relative layout be the parent node, with the same results.

Here is the .java for the custom dialog.

```
public class HandResults extends Dialog implements DialogInterface {
    HandResults hr;
    Timer myTimer;
    RelativeLayout handrl;


    // constructor sets the layout view to handresult layout
    public HandResults(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setContentView(R.layout.handresults);
        hr = this;

    }

    // create a timer to remove the dialog after 3 seconds
    public void showHands(){
        this.show();
        myTimer = null;
        myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                hr.cancel(); 
            }
        }, 3000);

    }
}
```

and here is how I would call the dialog:

```
HandResults mhr = new HandResults(this);
mhr.showHands();
```

no matter what I do or how I change the layout file, I always have that buffer at the top, how can I get rid of that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Put this code into class contstructor or onCreate() method:

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

It must be before calling setContentView method.

Comment: This wasn't working for me, but here is a solution that worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1693716/445348

Comment: how can I write it inside an adapter .. I can't access the method

Comment: got it !                                                       Dialog  warningDialog;                                                                                                     warningDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Comment: This didn't work for me because I was using AppCompatActivity, so I had to use `supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` and that fixed it for me.