# android: layout: How to make my dialog box fill the screen with the XML

Tags: android, layout, fill-parent

I'm trying to get a Dialog box to open covering most the screen (by that I mean it still has its nice  rounded effect but cover the content behind)

I've been trying with fill parent but it keeps behaving like a wrap content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 >


<LinearLayout
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="400px"
        android:layout_height="200px"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </SurfaceView>
    <Button android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Ok, Let me play !!!" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried the solution here

[How can I get a Dialog style activity window to fill the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362723/how-can-i-get-a-dialog-style-activity-window-to-fill-the-screen)

```
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

and it does what I want

so now I want to know what is worng in my xml (I try to put all layout behavior inside the xml rather than in my code if I can help it ^^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it the issue that the solution to [How can I get a Dialog style activity window to fill the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362723/how-can-i-get-a-dialog-style-activity-window-to-fill-the-screen) solved was that the layout had to be modified **after** the xml had been loaded. Basically there is no xml that can do this alone.

Answer (score 2):

Set a Transparent(glass.png)image as the background of the parent linearlayout of your xml.
The dialog will cover 90% of your screen.
You can find the required image glass.png by searching in google images.

Comment: Hey, can you help me get it to stretch and fill the entire screen, instead of just the pixel size of the png file?