# How to make an activity (displayed using Theme.dialog) occupy most of the screen - Android

Tags: android, android-activity

Android 2.3.3

I have an activity, that is displayed using the below code.

```
<activity android:name="com.xx.xxx.CombinationActivity"
    android:label=""
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">            
</activity>
```

Here is the Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <!-- Beginner / Intermediate and so on -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_choose_level_main_title_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/text_choose_level_main_title_1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_choose_level_1_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/text_choose_level_1_default_title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_choose_level_1_range"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/text_choose_level_1_default_range"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar_choose_level_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:max="100" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_choose_level_empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


    <!-- 2 / 3 / 4 / 5  -->
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_choose_level_main_title_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/text_choose_level_main_title_1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_choose_level_2_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/text_choose_level_1_default_title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_choose_level_2_range"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/text_choose_level_1_default_range"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar_choose_level_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:max="100" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I run the app, I get the what is displayed in first image. I need it to be as second image.

Thanks in advance..

What it is now :

[image]

What I want :

[image]

---

Answer :::

To those who are looking for the solution of similar kind, I have found the answer from @Marko comment. Thanks Marko..

Here is the link : [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362723/how-can-i-get-a-dialog-style-activity-window-to-fill-the-screen)

Here is the solution :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
}
```

Comment: Can you put in words whaat you want ? not able to see you image ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362723/how-can-i-get-a-dialog-style-activity-window-to-fill-the-screen seems like mathias answer is the one you want

Comment: When i run the application, I get the activity centered in the middle, with width equal to the text of any textview. I need it to occupy the entire screen,with 10dp margin.

Comment: @MarkoNiciforovic, I think it will work. I will give it a try..

Comment: @MarkoNiciforovic, would you like to give the same as an answer, so that I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your activity which has the Theme.Dialog style set, do this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im just guessing what you want..

I think you want the activity to fill your screen

Try this code

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

instead of

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Comment: but they both do the same, right? and I guess, fill_parent is deprecated and we are advised to use match_parent

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minWidth="1000dp"
```

Your dialog will now fill the screen width.