# Android make a dialog appear in fullscreen

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-fullscreen

I need the dialog to fill the screen except for some space at the top and the bottom.
I've search for a solution but couldn't find one probably because I'm declaring it in an `onClickListener`. 
Can someone please give a solution?

Activity code:

```
sort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                AlertDialog.Builder sort = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeScreen.this);
                // Get the layout inflater
                LayoutInflater inflater = HomeScreen.this.getLayoutInflater();
                View sortView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sort_layout, null);
                sort.setView(sortView);
                sort.create().show();
            }
        });
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_gravity="center">
    + some more stuff here I dont think it's relevant
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Check this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362723/how-can-i-get-a-dialog-style-activity-window-to-fill-the-screen

Comment: Already tried getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT) but it does nothing and it says it's deprecated.

Comment: you have make a custom style for that...

Comment: Where would I apply it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

here set your screen width and width to the dialog

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = width;
    lp.height = height;
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

or in your styles create a style like this then

```
 <style name="DialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">

    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>


    <!-- No backgrounds, titles or window float -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```

create a dialog object like this

```
dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.DialogTheme);
```

**Edit ::**

get width and height like this for any device it will fills..

```
WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Activity.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    int width, height;
    LayoutParams params;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
        width = manager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        height = manager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    } else {
        Point point = new Point();
        manager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(point);
        width = point.x;
        height = point.y;
    }
```

Comment: Your method kind of works but how do I set the values to fit the any screen?

Comment: It is working but I just used manager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() because point needs a higher API level and I'm developing for 2.2

Comment: Setting `<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>` won't five you an transparent background, but `<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>` will.

Answer (score 11):

first Make custom style for dialog in style.xml file:

```
<style name="full_screen_dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Then after set this theme to your Alert Dialog:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this,  R.style.full_screen_dialog));
```

Or You can call new Activity and Give this Custom style to that activity as a theme in your manifest file...

Comment: `windowIsFloating = true` adds to the dialog a margin from start and from end, how to resolve it?

Answer (score 4):

This may helpful for someone.
I want a dialog to take full width of screen. searched a lot but nothing found useful. Finally this worked for me:

```
mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_custom_dialog);
mDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

after adding this, my dialog appears in full width of screen.

Answer (score 3):

Make object like below theme

```
Dialog objD = new Dialog(this,     android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   Dialog dialog2 = new Dialog(context, R.style.DialogTheme);
    dialog2.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog2.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    dialog2.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_img);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog2.getWindow().getAttributes();
    Window window = dialog2.getWindow();
    lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    window.setAttributes(lp);
    lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    final ImageView imgprofile=(ImageView)dialog2.findViewById(R.id.img_centre);
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(arrayImages.get(position).get("image"))
            .resize(800,1000)
            .centerInside()
            .into(imgprofile, new Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    imgprofile.setImageResource(R.drawable.user);
                }
            });
    dialog2.show();
```

And in your dialog_img.xml file add an Imageview with scaleType(fitXY).

Answer (score 1):

I think you shoud try this one:

Inside the **dialogFragment**:

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of creating a full screen dialog, create a style like this:

```
<style name="DialogFullScreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DialogWhenLarge">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

then:

```
dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.DialogFullScreenTheme);
```