# Make a Dialogfragment in android full screen without actionbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to display a dialog fragment embeded inside another fragment but whenever it shows, There is a plain white background at the top occupying the space where the action bar normally goes.

How do i display full screen of the dialog?

Here is my dialog fragment.

```
public class HelpDialog extends DialogFragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Dialog dialog = getDialog();
        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);
            setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);

        }
    }
}
```

I have simple shown the dialog like this.

```
HelpDialog = new HelpDialog();
HelpDialog.show(fragmentManager, null);
```

Comment: Did you try using HelpDialog.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18315343/android-make-a-dialog-appear-in-fullscreen

Comment: dialog = new Dialog(parentActivity, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);

Comment: As of android build tools v23 the action bar is deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace setstyle with this

```
dialog.getWindow().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

And put before

```
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

Comment: i get android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Comment: You need to remove setstyle and put this before geWindow().getLayout()