# Dialog fragment not occupying complete screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment, android-layoutparams

I am opening dialog fragment. However, it does not occupy entire screen. I mean it leaves some space all side.

Below is my code :

```
    public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener{
        private Context context = getActivity();

        private ImageView imageViewCancel;
        private TextView textViewTitle;
        private View view;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutfile, container, false);

            getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            textViewTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_Screen_Title);
            setHeader("Some title");
            imageViewCancel = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_Cancel);
            imageViewCancel.setOnClickListener(this);


            //to hide keyboard when showing dialog fragment
            getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

            return view;
        }

        private void setHeader(String screenTitle) {
            textViewTitle.setText(screenTitle);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.imageView_Cancel :
                    dismiss();
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        }
    }
```

Refer snapshot

[image]

I want to open it in full screen mode so that background transparent will not be seen. Tried `WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` & `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` too but nothing works.

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18315343/android-make-a-dialog-appear-in-fullscreen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom style for `Dialog`

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="AppTheme" >
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
</style>
```

then use that style in dialog fragment

```
@Override public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.CustomDialog);
}

@Override public void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  getDialog().getWindow()
    .setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
}

SampleDialogFragment sampleDialogFragment = new SampleDialogFragment();
SampleDialogFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "sometag");
```

Comment: let me know the problem you have with it

Comment: Keep OR part only... above 1 didn't work on other device

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Add this in styles.xml

```
 <style name="MY.DIALOG" parent="android:Theme" >
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```

And set this style in your DialogFragment:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.MY_DIALOG);
}
```

The dialog fragment's background will appear black, change it according to your need.

Refer this post for more info:
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-unravel-the-mystery-of-androids-full-screen-dialog-fragments/