# custom dialog not coming properly

Tags: android, xml, customdialog

In my app, I tried to make custom dialog so I wrote an XML for that and In my XML its appearing like this,

[image]

dialog.xml,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical"
           >

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="50.0dip" 
                android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
                android:layout_margin="5.0dip">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewOTPDialogMessage" android:text="@string/OTPDialogActivityMessage" android:gravity="center" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#ff4d4d4d" 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textSize="18dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
       android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <View android:layout_marginTop="1.0dip" android:layout_below="@+id/textViewOTPDialogMessage" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dp" android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="50.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip">

   <TextView android:text="E-Mail Id OTP* " android:id="@+id/textViewEmailOTP" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#ff4d4d4d" 
       android:gravity="left"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dip" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
       android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

   <EditText  
       android:id="@+id/editTextEmailIdOtp" android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext" 
       android:paddingLeft="5.0dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="35.0dip" 
       android:layout_marginLeft="150.0dip" android:layout_marginRight="10.0dip" 
       android:singleLine="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
       android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:imeOptions="actionNext" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="50.0dip">

   <TextView android:text="Mobile OTP* " android:id="@+id/textViewMobileOTP" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#ff4d4d4d" 
       android:gravity="left" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dip" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
       android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

   <EditText  
       android:id="@+id/editTextMobileOtp" android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext" 
       android:paddingLeft="5.0dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="35.0dip" 
       android:layout_marginLeft="150.0dip" android:layout_marginRight="10.0dip" 
       android:singleLine="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:imeOptions="actionNext" />

</RelativeLayout>


<Button android:id="@+id/btnValidate" android:text="Validate" android:textSize="18.0sp" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#ff4d4d4d"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip" android:layout_marginBottom="10.0dip" />


</LinearLayout>
```

and when I am running it on my device then,

Its coming like this,

[image]

I tried to increase width size of dialog programmatically but getting no difference,

```
    private void callOTPDialog() 
    {
    Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(this);
    myDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    myDialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400);
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.otpdialog);
    myDialog.setCancelable(false);
    Button btnValidate = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnValidate);

    EditText email = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextEmailIdOtp);
    EditText mobile = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextMobileOtp);
    myDialog.show();

    btnValidate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v)
       {
               //your login calculation goes here
       }
   });


}
```

In XML I have mentioned these lines,

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

then also don't know what is happening here.

What to do now,

Please help,

Thanks.

Comment: also post your code pplz....

Comment: try like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20739136/1012284

Comment: @MD: Removed no difference :(

Comment: @Android what happened your problem solved or not?

Comment: @MD: Sorry I was doing lunch..Going to try

Comment: @Android ok if any doubts drop comment

Comment: @MD: android:backgroundDimEnabled requires API level 3 (current min is 1)

Comment: @Android you can remove this bcoz it's only for my requirement

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47932/discussion-between-android-and-m-d)

Comment: Removed but then also output is same...the only change is background got transparent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below:

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(Splash.this);

View DialogView = factory.inflate(
            R.layout.custom_progress_layout, null);

Dialog main_dialog = new Dialog(Splash.this,R.style.Theme_Dialog);
main_dialog.setContentView(DialogView);
main_dialog.show();
```

And create `Theme_Dialog` into `values\styles.xml`

```
  <style name="Theme_Dialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

This is perfect working in my case.

**Update:** you just need to change both your `RelativeLayout` attribute width with  `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` into your `layout.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

add the following line in your code:

```
myDialog.setWindowLayoutMode(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature((int) Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_here);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Try this one

Answer (score 1):

put this code in `OnCreate` of your `Dialogue`

```
getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found same problem before and i tried to fix with this

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    LayoutParams params = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(params);      
}
```

hope it helps