# Custom dialog works wrong on android 7.1.1

Tags: android

Hi im working with custom dialog in android, 
my code:

```
public void generarDialogoParametros(String titulo, boolean llamaNumero) {
    Dialog dialogo = new Dialog(context,R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
    dialogo.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialogo.setContentView(R.layout.dialogo_parametros);
    dialogo.setTitle(titulo);
    TextView spo2 = (TextView) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.editTextSPO2);
    TextView pulsobajo = (TextView) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.editTextPulsoAlto);
    TextView pulsoalto = (TextView) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.editTextPulsoBajo);
    Button guardar = (Button) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.btnAceptarParametros);
    Button cancelar = (Button) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelarParametros);
    spo2.setText(preferencias.getSPO2() + "");
    pulsoalto.setText(preferencias.getPulsoAlto() + "");
    pulsobajo.setText(preferencias.getPulsoBajo() + "");
    guardarParametrosNuevos(guardar,cancelar, dialogo, spo2, pulsoalto, pulsobajo, llamaNumero);
    dialogo.show();
    dialogo.setCancelable(false);
}
```

in android 4,5,6 works like:

[image]

But in 7+

[image]

I dont know, how i'm fix it can help me?

Comment: I faced same Problem before 2 days. In my case, I used Linear Layout as Parent Layout, I fixed it correct by Using RelativeLayout instead of Linear Layout. You can try this. Hope this help you.

Comment: @BhoomikaPatel may be you are right but but it can also achieve  using  **`Window`**  to  set width and hight programatically of dialog

Comment: Refer this Link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362723/how-can-i-get-a-dialog-style-activity-window-to-fill-the-screen

Comment: @Prem Yes you can, But in most of cases it is not working. Thats why i gave you this solution. :)

Comment: **But in most of cases it is not working** it working in all cases @BhoomikaPatel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this  set hight and width of your dialog programatically using below code

```
    public void generarDialogoParametros(String titulo, boolean llamaNumero) {
            Dialog dialogo = new Dialog(context,R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
            dialogo.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialogo.setContentView(R.layout.dialogo_parametros);
            Window window = dialogo.getWindow();
            window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            dialogo.setTitle(titulo);
            TextView spo2 = (TextView) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.editTextSPO2);
            TextView pulsobajo = (TextView) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.editTextPulsoAlto);
            TextView pulsoalto = (TextView) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.editTextPulsoBajo);
            Button guardar = (Button) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.btnAceptarParametros);
            Button cancelar = (Button) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelarParametros);
            spo2.setText(preferencias.getSPO2() + "");
            pulsoalto.setText(preferencias.getPulsoAlto() + "");
            pulsobajo.setText(preferencias.getPulsoBajo() + "");
            guardarParametrosNuevos(guardar,cancelar, dialogo, spo2, pulsoalto, pulsobajo, llamaNumero);
            dialogo.show();
            dialogo.setCancelable(false);
        }
```